# How can I insert featured image from media library in frontend post form

Tags: wordpress, frontend

I am creating a form on my Wordpress site.

1. I want to add a custom field in the form that allows the user to attach an image to use as the featured image.
2. I also want to be able to insert the image from a media library.

What code would allow me to add a custom field like this to the form?

Comment: Please clarify your intentions. Do you want users to be able to attach images from their computer? What media library are you hoping to provide access to? What have you tried so far?

Comment: When we publish post from wp-admin we set featured image by clicking "set featured image" and open a window. I called the window media library..Have any code so that, user can set featured image from the window in frontend?

Answer (score 0):

The Best Solution : https://wordpress.org/plugins/user-submitted-posts/ Custom Fields + Upload Image Front-end

Comment: thanks for trying to helping but it doesn't solved my purpose.